# Problem with \vdotswithin

Tags: equations, mathtools, alignat

I want to typeset a system of equations and set vertical dots between two rows centered at the equal sign. *vdotswithin* from 'mathtools' should do exactly that, but for some reason the following code

```
\begin{alignat*}{3}
x_1 &+ x_2 t_1 &= 0\\
x_1 &+ x_2 t_2 &= 0\\
&&\vdotswithin{=}\\
x_1 &+ x_2 t_m &= 0
\end{alignat*}
```

produces the following output
[image]

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that your last column is set up for right, rather than left alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
x_1 +{} &&x_2 t_1 &= 0\\
x_1 +{} &&x_2 t_2 &= 0\\
&&&\vdotswithin{=}\\
x_1 + {}&&x_2 t_m &= 0
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there any documentation which explains the logic behind the '&' and '{}'? There usage seems to be nontrivial in amsmath.

Comment: @Dominik The `{}` has to do with  letting the `+` know that something follows (in the next column), since technically, the `+` can't otherwise tell what follows the `&`.  The `&` are, of course, column separators.  The use of `&=` rather than `&=` is a quirk of `amsmath` that, to be honest, I don't wholly comprehend.  But the underlying lesson is that the spacing around things like `+` and `-` will vary depending on if it is used in a binary or unary sense.  The `{}` helps clarify the sense.

Answer (score 5):

I would do it this way:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
x_1 &+ x_2 t_1 &&= 0\\
x_1 &+ x_2 t_2 &&= 0\\
    &          && \vdotswithin{=} \\
x_1 &+ x_2 t_m &&= 0
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Every time you have a `&` in one of the `align` environments, the alignment type switches between left and right. The first column is always right-aligned. Therefore, here, column alignments are respectively: right, left, right, and left.

Then, regarding the mandatory argument of `alignat`, the `amsmath` documentation (amsldoc.pdf) says:

[image: doc on alignat]

Here, we have three `&` in each line, therefore the correct argument to pass to `alignat` is (3+1)/2 = 2, not 3. This is the number of (right, left ) pairs of columns.

In case you want the dots to be closer to the equal signs, I believe one way to do it should be:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
x_1 &+ x_2 t_1 &&= 0\\
x_1 &+ x_2 t_2 &&= 0\\
\MTFlushSpaceAbove
    &          && \vdotswithin{=}
\MTFlushSpaceBelow
x_1 &+ x_2 t_m &&= 0
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]